# Get post categories without parent category, but show other non parent-child categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Some of my categories have parent categories, and some don't. What I need is a way to show only categories without parent, and child categories.

So for instance I have

```
Cat 1
Cat 2 
Cat 3
 - Cat 3.1
 - Cat 3.2
Cat 4
Cat 5
```

And my post has `Cat 1`, `Cat 3`and `Cat 3.1` on it (permalink reasons - I need to set the parent category as well). With this:

```
$category_out=array();
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category_one) {
    $category_out[] ='<a class="' .$category_one->slug.'" href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category_one->term_id ) ).'">' .$category_one->name.'</a>';
}
$category_out = implode( '', $category_out);
```

I will get out in my `$category_out` `Cat 1`, `Cat 3` and `Cat 3.1`. And I don't wan't `Cat 3` to be in the list.

I tried with

```
$category_out=array();
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category_one) {
    if ($category_one->category_parent != 0) {
        $category_out[] ='<a class="' .$category_one->slug.'" href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category_one->term_id ) ).'">' .$category_one->name.'</a>'
    }
}
$category_out = implode( '', $category_out);
```

But this shows only `Cat 3.1` since, technically, `Cat 1-5` are all parent categories to themselves.

Is there a way to show only subcategories of existing parent category and other non parent-child related categories in a category list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use get_term_children to achieve this !

The loop :

```
foreach ($categories as $category_one) {
    if (empty(get_term_children($category_one->term_id,$category_one->taxonomy))){
    $category_out[] ='<a class="' .$category_one->slug.'" href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category_one->term_id ) ).'">' .$category_one->name.'</a>';
    }
}
```